# Create notification by webworker

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, web-worker

In [article about notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) Mozzila says:

> **Note:** This feature is available in Web Workers.

Worker can be created without any warnings

```
var worker = new SharedWorker('scripts/worker.js');
```

But when I try to do this inside shared worker:

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
```

It doesn't work. Webworker works fine, it does a `XMLHttpRequest`, it can read data from main thread and push messages to it but notification doesn't appear. I can't debug it because console is unavailable inside webworker. Permission was granted in main thread and the notifications are also available here.

If it is important I use Chrome `47.0.2526.111 m` for developing and debugging. I noticed that Facebook invokes notifications even when FB tab is closed so I am trying to implement something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing something wrong. I had absolutely **no problems** running notifications in web workers.

This code works perfectly on jsfiddle:

- **[`Worker` example](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/9e7xycky/4/)**
- **[`SharedWorker` example](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/0gwrk9qz/3/)**

Please try following code:

#### `main.js`

```
var worker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");
worker.port.start();    
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
  if (permission === "granted") {
    worker.port.postMessage({name:"notification"});
  }
});
```

#### `worker.js`

```
function workerFN() {
  function onmessage(e) {
    switch(e.data.name) {
      case "notification" : 
        console.log("Notification:");
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      break;
      default:
        console.error("Unknown message:", e.data.name);
    }
  }
  self.onconnect = function(e) {
      for(var i=0,l=e.ports.length; i<l; i++) {
        e.ports[i].addEventListener('message', onmessage);
        e.ports[i].start(); // Required when using addEventListener. Otherwise called implicitly by onmessage setter.
      }
  }
}
```

Also console works quite well for me in web workers.

Comment: problem is when some error takes place worker can't notify about that in console like code in main thread does. Thanks for trick, it is very useful to debug worker's code in the main thread and when it is ready just move it to worker's file.

Comment: There's one other trick - worker also can have [`onerror` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbstractWorker/onerror).